# Is there a way to process the queued webhook in ADO?

Tags: azure-devops, webhooks, azure-service-hooks

We have a service hook created for one of our projects in ADO. It was going fine until last weekend. Suddenly few webhooks started queued and I am not sure how to force it to get processed. Can someone help me if there is a way to force those items to get processed.

Thanks,
Venu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I am afraid that you cannot get that you want during process.**

Under the process, the queued service hooks will not be picked again and will not be processed again.

When the main thread, such as a work item, is running, you cannot forcefully intervene or exit the content that is already queued.
And there is [a similar issue also discussing about this situation](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Many-service-hooks-queued-for-multiple/1254560).

And waiting service hooks are actually coupled, which also depends on your memory, because they actually run in memory. If there are occasional memory loss and other problems during execution, this cannot ensure that all service hooks can be executed as expected.

Or you should interrupt the current process and reduce the service hooks for it. But it is not a good solution.

**So** it is the best way to add a function that can handle the queued service hooks in the process. But currently there is no such function. Therefore we recommend you [submit the suggestion ticket to the Team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to suggest them add that feature.

[image]